# Adding associated double values from database when checkedlistbox item is selected

Tags: vb.net

**Edited**

Hi I have this program where I need to display the sum of the values when read from the database. I tried something like this:

```
 Dim selec As String
    Dim con As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\rose&mike\Desktop\DbSysDel3\salondbaccess.accdb")
    Dim dt2 As New DataTable
    selec = ""
    con.Open()
    For Each incheck In chcklstbx1.CheckedIndices
        Dim valName As String
        valName = chcklstbx1.Items.Item(incheck).ToString
        Dim sqlstr2 As String = "SELECT Service_Fee FROM Service_Types WHERE [Service_Name] = '" & valName & "'"
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(sqlstr2, con)
        Dim sum As Double = 0
        Dim rdr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
        If rdr.HasRows Then
            While rdr.Read
                selec += "P" + rdr("Service_Fee").ToString & ControlChars.NewLine
                sum = sum + rdr("Service_Fee")

            End While
        End If
        lblFees.Text = selec
        lblTotal.Text = sum.ToString
        rdr.Close()
    Next
    con.Close()
```

But all it does is display the values I want to add one by one when checked.

Comment: I cant see anywhere that you are qualifying the query or loop based on a CheckedListBox - it doesnt appear anywhere in the code.

Comment: Why dont you [edit] your post so we can read that

Comment: @Plutonix yes I already did. Please take a look. Thank you.

Comment: the `Service_Fee` datatype in the database is currency

Comment: Do you mean to say that you want to populate the `CheckedListBox` and then, when the user checks items, you want to sum the numeric values associated with those items?

Comment: @jmcilhinney i have already populated the checkedlistbox from my database and yes i want to sum the numeric values (Currency datatype in the database) associated with them.

Comment: I'm not sure what's technically wrong with the code you have but your design is very, very bad.  There's no reason to query the database more than once.  I'll post an answer that demonstrates how it should be done, with one query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of how this whole thing should be handled:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Using connection As New OleDbConnection("connection string here"),
          adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT Name, Amount FROM MyTable", connection)
        Dim table As New DataTable

        adapter.Fill(table)

        'Bind the DataTable to the CheckedListBox.
        'Normally the DataSource should be set last but, in my experience, that can cause problems with a CheckedListBox.
        With CheckedListBox1
            .DataSource = table
            .DisplayMember = "Name"
            .ValueMember = "Amount"
        End With
    End Using
End Sub

Private Sub CheckedListBox1_ItemCheck(sender As Object, e As ItemCheckEventArgs) Handles CheckedListBox1.ItemCheck
    'Get all the currently checked items.
    Dim checkedItems = CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems.Cast(Of DataRowView)().ToList()

    'Get the item that is being checked or unchecked.
    Dim currentItem = DirectCast(CheckedListBox1.Items(e.Index), DataRowView)

    If e.NewValue = CheckState.Checked Then
        'The current item is being checked so add it to the list.
        checkedItems.Add(currentItem)
    Else
        'The current item is being unchecked so remove it from the list.
        checkedItems.Remove(currentItem)
    End If

    'Sum the Amounts from each checked item.
    Dim sum = checkedItems.Sum(Function(drv) CDec(drv("Amount")))

    'Use sum here.
    '...
End Sub
```

You get all the data up front, including all the text to display and all the associated numeric values.  That data can be bound to the `CheckedListBox` as a `DataTable`, keeping it all packaged together.

Each time the user checks or unchecks an item in the list, you perform the calculation based on the data you already have.  No need to go back to the database.

The important thing to note about the `ItemCheck` event is that it is raised BEFORE the item is checked or unchecked.  That's why the code needs to ad the current item, or remove it from, the list of checked items.

When you bind a `DataTable`, each bound item is a `DataRowView`, i.e. an item from the table's `DefaultView`.  You get all the checked `DataRowView` items, get their numeric value and sum them.  Note that I've used a LINQ query to calculate the sum succinctly but you could use a loop if you wanted to, e.g.

```
Dim sum As Decimal = 0D

For Each drv In checkedItems
    sum += CDec(drv("Amount"))
Next
```

Comment: I'm actually very new to VB.Net so I apologize if my design is bad. I'll try using the sample that you gave as reference, thank you.

Comment: There's no need to apologise. My app designs were bad when I started out too. I'm not judging when I say that someone's code is bad. I'm just emphasising why a significant change in the code is warranted.

Comment: Thank you so much @jmcilhinney it worked great. But now I don't know how to display the individual amounts of the items checked, that's what I use `selec` for. Any suggestions on how I should do it properly?

Comment: I've shown you two ways to GET the values. What you then do with those values is up to you.  For instance, in the loop I provided in the last code snippet, you can simply convert the number to a `String` and then concatenate that to another `String` instead of adding it to another number.  The LINQ version could look like this: `Dim text = String.Join(", ", checkedItems.Select(Function(drv) CDec(drv("Amount"))))`.

Comment: You are a great help @jmcilhinney thank you very much.I chose to use the LINQ version but replaced the joining commas as `ControlChars.NewLine` .